# How to split the query response of 2 metric in to two

Tags: bash, shell, jq

PROMETHEUS_METRIC: { **name**: sc_pcd_g2version, container: mgmtbroker, endpoint: vxexporter, instance: 10.42.24.132:9116, job: prometheus, namespace: delivery, pod: chn1-d1-ac-0, service: prometheus }{ **name**: sc_pcd_g2version, container: mgmtbroker, endpoint: vxexporter, instance: 10.42.3.110:9116, job: prometheus, namespace: delivery, pod: chn1-d1-ia-0, service: prometheus }

Its json format. How to split the above response into 2 as below in shell script. I have variable PROMETHEUS_METRIC have the above json.

```
{ __name__: sc_pcd_g2version, container: mgmtbroker, endpoint: vxexporter, instance: 10.42.24.132:9116, job: prometheus, namespace: delivery, pod: chn1-d1-ac-0, service: prometheus }

{ __name__: sc_pcd_g2version, container: mgmtbroker, endpoint: vxexporter, instance: 10.42.3.110:9116, job: prometheus, namespace: delivery, pod: chn1-d1-ia-0, service: prometheus }
```

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Where does this come from? From a file or from stdin?

Comment: This is response from a file and it return  response of two metrics in {} which needs to be iterated and splitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the input nor the desired output is valid JSON. Thus, treating input and output as raw text (using jq with flags `-Rr`, although at this point you could use any JSON-unrelated text-processing tool), you could simply scan by regular expressions, for instance from `{` to `}`:

```bash
jq -Rr 'scan("({[^}]*})")[]'
```

```
{ __name__: sc_pcd_g2version, container: mgmtbroker, endpoint: vxexporter, instance: 10.42.24.132:9116, job: prometheus, namespace: delivery, pod: chn1-d1-ac-0, service: prometheus }
{ __name__: sc_pcd_g2version, container: mgmtbroker, endpoint: vxexporter, instance: 10.42.3.110:9116, job: prometheus, namespace: delivery, pod: chn1-d1-ia-0, service: prometheus }
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jD4pBjSIbBZ)

Comment: I think it makes sense to wait with an answer until the questioner has shown what he has tried to answer the question himself.